# Macro Error - Next without For

Tags: vba

I have the following code to hide the columns with zero value in it for the defined range. Not sure why I always get the "Next without For" error. Can anyone help? Thanks.

```
Sub hidecolumns1()

Dim rRange As Range
Dim rCell As Range

Set rRange = Worksheets("Income Statement - Rollover").Range("B54:KZ54").Cells
'Set rRange = Selection.Cells

    For Each rCell In rRange
        If rCell.Text <> "" Then
        rCell.Columns.EntireColumn.Hidden = True
    Next rCell

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You're missing an `end if`:

```
Sub hidecolumns1()

Dim rRange As Range
Dim rCell As Range

Set rRange = Worksheets("Income Statement - Rollover").Range("B54:KZ54").Cells
'Set rRange = Selection.Cells

    For Each rCell In rRange
        If rCell.Text <> "" Then
            rCell.Columns.EntireColumn.Hidden = True
        End If '<---
    Next rCell

End Sub
```

Comment: Or you have a linefeed more...  If rCell.Text <> "" rCell.Columns.EntireColumn.Hidden = True

Comment: Cheers, mate! Happy coding to you :-)